# How to increment hour in for loop

Tags: c#, wpf

For a school exercise I have to make a text clock in a WPF application that will give you the time in text. What I want is for example: when it's 10:30, the clock should say half past ten which in Dutch would be 'a half before 11', 'Half 11'. But I'm not sure how to do it in this for loop I tried `i++;` but that didn't increment the hour.

Please keep in mind that I just started coding so there are probably a lot of mistakes I've made either way here's the code.

I hope it's clear for everyone otherwise I'll change everything to English.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var date = DateTime.Now;

        TijdHet.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        TijdIs.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        var time = new Label[]
        {
            TijdEen, TijdTwee, TijdDrie, TijdVier, TijdVijf, TijdZes, TijdZeven, TijdAcht, TijdNegen, TijdTien,
            TijdElf, TijdTwaalf
        };

        int GetMinutes() {
            var minutes = 5 * (int) Math.Round(date.Minute / 5.0);
            return minutes;
        }

        int GetHour()
        {
            var hour = (date.Hour + 11) % 12 + 1;

            if (hour == 1) {
                TijdEen.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }

            return hour;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            if (GetHour() == i + 1)
            {
                time[i].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                if (GetMinutes() == 0) {
                    TijdUur.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }

                if (GetMinutes() == 5 || GetMinutes() == 10 || GetMinutes() == 35 || GetMinutes() == 40) {
                    TijdOver.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }

                if (GetMinutes() == 20 || GetMinutes() == 25 || GetMinutes() == 50 || GetMinutes() == 55) {
                    TijdVoor.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }

                if (GetMinutes() == 30)  {
                    TijdHalf.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry one thing I don't get is dose this need to be an active clock? Change labels as time passes or is it only required on startup?

Comment: I think you've posted more code than needed here. You stated *"What I want is for example: when it's 10:30, the clock should say half past ten which in Dutch would be 'a half before 11', 'Half 11'."*, which to me sounds like you need a method that takes in a `DateTime` and returns a formatted string. Then you would just call this method from wherever you want to display "Half 11" to the user. I don't see anything like that in your code, which is confusing. It seems you're just setting a foreground color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example program that outputs the time as a string - it should be easily adaptable to use your array of labels & Dutch phrasing :

```
void Main()
{
  string[] hours = { "Twelve", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven"};
  string[] minutes = { "O'Clock", "Five", "Ten", "Quarter", "Twenty", "TwentyFive", "Half", "TwentyFive", "Twenty", "Quarter", "Ten", "Five"};

  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

  int HourOffset = now.Hour % 12;
  int MinOffset = (now.Minute / 5);

  string TimeStr, ConStr;
  if (MinOffset == 0)
    TimeStr = hours[HourOffset] + " " + minutes[0];
  else
  {
    if (MinOffset >= 6)
    {
      ConStr = " To ";
      HourOffset++;
      HourOffset %= 12;
    }
    else
      ConStr = " Past ";
    TimeStr = minutes[MinOffset] + ConStr + hours[HourOffset];
  }

  Console.WriteLine(TimeStr);
}
```

Note that you do not need a for loop if you are only displaying the current time.

First get the hours as an offset into a twelve element hours string array.
Then get the minutes, divided down by five as an offset into a text minutes string array.

When you need to increment the hour - you also need to ensure that it is mod'ed by twelve to get the correct offset into the array.

Answer (score 2):

This is just psuedo code but will show you what you need to do to increment your hour

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

so, in your code you simply need to do

```
date.AddHours(1);
```

hopefully this should give you enough to go on with

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately this doesn't work it gives me this warning:
"Return value of pure method is not used" not sure why.

Comment: @Ezrab_ It should be `date = date.AddHours(1)` because it creates a new `DateTime`.

Comment: @juharr Also doesn't work because now it makes almost every text red.

Comment: @Ezrab_ Don't forget the `;` at the end of any statement like I did.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a little hard to follow with the setting of the colors on the controls.
Here's some code that'll print out the time like a human would say it. I hope you can adapt it to setting the colors on your controls.

```
static void PrintTime(int hours, int minutes)
{
    if (minutes >= 30)
    {
         hours++;
         minutes -= 60;
    }
    hours = hours % 12;
    if (hours == 0) hours = 12;
    Console.WriteLine("The time is " + Math.Abs(minutes) + (minutes < 0 ? " to " : " past ") + hours);
}
```

if you call it like this

```
PrintTime(10, 29);
PrintTime(10, 30);
PrintTime(10, 31);
```

it'll print

```
The time is 29 past 10
The time is 30 to 11
The time is 29 to 11
```